# Check if newly released iOS app is worldwide available on the AppStore

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I will release my iOS app soon and I read that there is a delay for up to 5 hours until the app is available on the AppStore worldwide. I'm in Austria (Europe), how can I check if the app is already available on the US AppStore? (or better yet if it's available everywhere)

Comment: Wait a whole day before starting your ad campaign?

Comment: There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Propagation is an eternal issue, especially if you're not in charge of the propagation method. Apple take their own sites offline for a period before an important release, so the 'switch on' can be simultaneous. The rest of us don't have that luxury ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only know of a manual way checking it.

Open App Store and click at the flag circle bottom right.

[image: flag]

Now select the country you want to check for your app.

[image: select country]